# why do my trackers not align properly with in the view port compared to the clip editor?

Tags: tracking

as you can see in the below images the trackers in the clip editor aren't in the right place in the view port (to see it clearly look at the highlighted marker). This influences the scene and when I try to place objects they don't follow the camera motion

I have followed the appropriate steps to track a the video, but when I pres setup tracking scene and set the right trackers as floor with origin and y and x axis's and scale.

What do I need to do to make the trackers align?

[image: screenshot of blender from the camera view]

[image: screenshot of the scene outside of the camera perspective]